# QField - switch between multiple layer styles

Tags: qgis, style, qfield

In QField (1.4.4) demo project - Advanced Bee Farming Demo - there is an option to switch between layer styles (Diseases, Heatmap, Species). How to set up a project in QGis to enable this function in custom project?

Creating multiple styles per layer is not enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use map theme, that's what Qfield use to switch between different map style (map theme reference what styles to use for each layer, so creating multiple styles per layer is the first step)

[Map themes in QGIS documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html?highlight=theme#configuring-map-themes)

[QField Documentation : Configure Map Themes](https://qfield.org/docs/project-management/map-themes.html)